# Solaris configuration file parser

Tags: c++, c, parsing, solaris, glib

Is there any api in `Solaris` for configuration file parsing. Currently I am using `GLib's` `GKeyFile` Parser in Linux, but need to port the application into Solaris. Don't want to compile `glib` on Solaris.

Answer (score 1):

Since [GNOME has been included in Solaris since Solaris 9 8/03 released almost exactly 10 years ago](http://www.osnews.com/story/4154), most Solaris systems already have some version of glib available.

Comment: Don't want to add gnome dependency in my application. Really surprised what library lot of Solaris application used for configuration file reading.